# Android Notification Inside Method Does't Work

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have this code not working when calling ***MakeNotification()*** from other areas in the program except the ***onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState***) method, which only there the notification is working.

please help ;-)

```
public void MakeNotification() {
    // notify
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("Tie")
                    .setContentText("Clipboard cleared");

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mNotificationManager.notify(1212, mBuilder.build());
}
```

I.E: tried to call ***MakeNotification()*** from here:

```
    public void delayedClearTextview(final Handler handler, final TextView txt) {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask delayedTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    txt.setText(R.string.opt); 
                    MakeNotification() // <<<<<----- WILL NOT WORK !!!! <<<<
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(delayedTask, (1000));
```

EDIT: the only problem is that notification is not showen when calling the MakeNotification() method from another method. Am I missing something here ? :()

Comment: Wha is the error?. Show me the error log.

Comment: If the log has som' to do with not using the main thread, you should: run the method from a runnable passed to runOnUiThread

Comment: No error occurred. But no notification either!